# Guilds not working on iOS?

Tags: ios, clicker-heroes

I've been trying to join a guild for the past week and every time I choose "Random Search" it will prompt me that there are no available guilds to join.

I can search for guilds manually by name but even if the guild has 1 player in it I am told "this guild is full".

How can I join a guild without making my own?

Comment: This error appeared in my game too, but I tried it just more often (at different times). Out of 5 tries it worked once and I applied for a guild. It seems to be kinda buggy or sth like that; try again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guild feature is fairly new to the game, therefore it has some problems, one being balance (it's way too easy to get further in the game if you're in a guild) and two being general bugs such as the problem you're having.

This happened to me many times at first and the only way you can "fix" it is to just keep trying. I suspect it's telling you that because it doesn't check available guilds thoroughly enough. Keep trying and you'll eventually get results to come up.

If you want to join a guild without having to use the search, check the Clicker Heroes reddit page for quick opportunities.